# Where to add a surface to a grasshopper definition to create result shown?

Tags: grasshopper

I am trying to figure out where to add a surface input in a grasshopper definition in order for the resulting rectangles into the surface provided.

First picture is my grasshopper definition with the unconnected surface I set.

[image: grasshopper definition]

Second picture is the current output.

[image: current output]

Third picture is what I am trying to create.

[image: desired output]

Fourth picture is the surface input.

[image: surface input]

The colors do not matter it is just the

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely have to map or orient that unit object to the target rectangular surfaces. Not a single component. Please share the script so others can help you better.